# SlickGrid - Cleanly Cancel Edit within Editor Constructor

Tags: slickgrid

I'd like to cancel an edit from within the constructor of a custom editor and cause the active cell to lose focus. Currently, I can call `cancelEdit` from the object passed into the constructor, but I also have to use flags within `loadValue`, `isValueChanged`, `serializeValue` and `destroy` to check if the premature cancel occurred. Also, the cell does not lose focus when this happens.

Is this possible?

**Edit**

Below is a snippet of the constructor for the editor. It allows for registering(adding) an editor and assigning it a name. On invocation, the editor gets the value of the `args.item.type` and tries to retrieve the editor that was registered for that value. What's not shown is code that just follows the delegation pattern, which causes the `MyConstructor` instance to delegate work to its internal editor instance.

If there is no editor that matches the value of `args.item.type`, the constructor tries to cancel the edit.

```
MyConstructor = (function(){

    var editors = {}
    var defaultEditor = TextCellEditor

    constructorFn = function(args){
        this.init(args)
    }

    constructorFn.overridesEnabled = false
    constructorFn.defaultEditorEnabled = true;

    constructorFn.prototype.init = function(args){
        var editorExists = function(dataType){
            if(dataType in editors){
                return true
            }

            if(constructorFn.defaultEditorEnabled){
                return true
            }

            return false
        }

        var getEditor = function(args){
            if(args.item.type in editors){
                editorConstructor = editors[args.item.type]
                return new editorConstructor(args)
            }
            else{
                editorConstructor = defaultEditor
                return new editorConstructor(args)
            }
        }

        if(editorExists(args.item.type))
        {
            this.superClass.init.call(args)
            this.editor = getEditor(args)
        }
        else{
            debug.error("Prematurely destroying editor")
            args.cancelChanges()
            this.mumps = true
        }  
    }

    constructorFn.registerEditor = function(name, constructor){
        if(name in editors){
            if(constructorFn.overridesEnabled){
                editors[name] = constructor
            }
            else{
                //Log error
                debug.error("Cannot override existing constructor: " + name)
            }
        }
        else{
            editors[name] = constructor
        }
    }
})()
```

Comment: The `Esc` key does this already for a grid editor. Maybe you could look into how that is handled. Or even trigger the `Esc` key-press programmatically and handle the keydown event. Just a thought.

Comment: I'll try firing a key event for `Esc`.

But then I'm confused as to when you're supposed to use the methods `cancelEdit` and `commitEdit` that are properties of the object passed to any editor constructor. Also, the logic flow for editors is interesting. `loadValue` and `serializeValue` seem to be called immediately without checking if the constructor successfully completed. I could also be trying to use the constructor incorrectly.

Comment: Valid argument - can you post your code on how you are trying to handle this now?

Comment: I edited the original question with some code. Also, I tried firing a keydown event for `Esc`, but unfortunately I am still seeing the same behavior.